# python regular expression handling bracket

Tags: python, regex

```
string = '1f23wsedrfth 567tgyh112'
expectedChecksum = re.search( "[0-9a-f]{5}",string ).group(0)


 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Why is it caused an error? I thought the expectedChecksum should be `'1f23w'`

I tried the following code with `{4}`, then it is fine.

```
expectedChecksum = re.search( "[0-9a-f]{4}",string ).group(0)
expectedChecksum
'1f23'
```

Comment: `w` is between `a-f`?

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you check for characters from a to f but in your string there is an w at 5th position. This might cause the error.
When you try with {4} you not cheking for the w so it's not throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Strings with numbers `0-9` and letters `a-f` are the only ones the will match with your specified regex `[0-9a-f]`. Therefore, the `search function` will return a `NoneType object` when it evaluates a string that do not match your regex which in turn raises an error because there is not attribute `group` for a `Nonetype object`.

I guess your desired regex is `[0-9a-z]` unless there would be a much more complicated combinations and ordering.

You can further test your regex with [pythex](https://pythex.org/) to see what strings will match to your regex.